# Frechet Derivative: Why bounded (linear) operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Why do we want the frechet derivative to be a *bounded* linear operator?
(This meant more as a collecting ideas - I know bounded operators behave fine but that would exclude alot of examples such as the unbounded differentiation operator)

Comment: because if derivative is not continuous there will no be big progress in future research. Amount of results on continuously differentiable fnctions is much more than with discontinuous ones

Comment: Well, yeah, but what about important unbounded linear operators then?

Comment: Study of unbounded operators that arise in practice is a kind of hack-work (imho) , so biulding a general theory for them is pointless as you can't say much useful about these objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Norbert:

> Study of unbounded operators that arise in practice is a kind of hack-work (imho) , so biulding a general theory for them is pointless as you can't say much useful about these objects.